# Moving Visuals via dedicated thread?

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading

Is it possible to dedicate a thread to handle the animation of Visuals in my WPF app?
To explain more, in my app, some times there are heavy tasks, which will effect the math-based animation of moivng Visuals.

So, is this possible? to keep the animation smooth using a dedicated thread?

**EDIT**

Here is how I move the Visuals:

```
public class KMouseGrid : Grid
{
private VisualCollection _children;
DrawingVisual DrawingVisual_0;
TranslateTransform _0_translate = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);
DrawingVisual DrawingVisual_1;
TranslateTransform _1_translate = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);

public KMouseGrid()
        {
            MultiInputWrapper.Instance.CoordinateRecieved += new MultiInput.Contracts.MultiInput(Instance_CoordinateRecievedSingleChannel);

            _children.Add(DrawingVisual_0);
            _children.Add(DrawingVisual_1);

        }
void Instance_CoordinateRecievedMultiChannel(double aX, double aY, int aChanelNumber, MultiInput.Contracts.MouseEvents aMouseEvent)
        {
            if (aChanelNumber == 0)
            {
                _0_translate.X = MultiInput.MultiInputMouse.GetLastPosition(0).X  ;
                _0_translate.Y = MultiInput.MultiInputMouse.GetLastPosition(0).Y ;
                //_0_rotate.Angle += 6;
            }
            else if (aChanelNumber == 1)
            {
                _1_translate.X = MultiInput.MultiInputMouse.GetLastPosition(1).X   ;
                _1_translate.Y = MultiInput.MultiInputMouse.GetLastPosition(1).Y  ;
            }


        }


// Provide a required override for the VisualChildrenCount property. 
        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get
            {
                if (_children == null)
                {
                    _children = new VisualCollection(this);
                }
                return _children.Count;
            }
        }

        // Provide a required override for the GetVisualChild method. 
        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= _children.Count)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            return _children[index];
        }


private DrawingVisual CreateDrawingVisualCursor(ImageSource aImageSource, double aXOffset, double aYOffset)
        {
            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

            // Retrieve the DrawingContext in order to create new drawing content.
            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

            // Create a rectangle and draw it in the DrawingContext.
            Rect rect = new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(aXOffset, aYOffset), new System.Windows.Size(aImageSource.Width, aImageSource.Height));
            drawingContext.DrawImage(aImageSource, rect);

            // Persist the drawing content.
            drawingContext.Close();

            return drawingVisual;
        }
```

Comment: Depends on what your "math-based" animations are. You should share some details.

Comment: Basically, I am just moving Visuals using X, Y of mouse coordinates that I read from sent messages from Windows to WPF app through WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)

Comment: I don't understand the WndProc thing. There is mouse input handling in WPF. And you still haven't said how you actually "move" the Visuals. By their [Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.containervisual.transform.aspx) property perhaps? Why don't you post the relevant code parts?

Comment: May be its important to know the source of coordinates, please see the EDIT above, I hope you get the general picture, I tried to take the code that counts most, as its a long class here ..

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around, i.e. "heavy tasks" in a separate threads and UI animation in the UI thread ?

Comment: And `_0_translate` is assigned to `DrawingVisual_0.Transform` etc.? Ok, now where is the time-consuming method that you want to execute in a separate thread?

Comment: I think Nicolas has a good suggestion, to put the heavy tasks in a separate thread, @Clemens; your question opened my eyes on the fact that all the logic above in the EDIT should be kept assigned to the UI thread, as there isn't heavy logic already, What I am trying to do is to have a virtual cursors instead of real mouse in my multi-input app, what do you suggest to keep it always responsive?